# Why turns the string to empty?

Tags: java

If I run this code the first 28 lines of the append.txt are full of numbers but then it is empty, why? It should also contains some numbers!!
Is the String get too big?

```
    try {
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("append.txt"), true);
        String seq = "11", output = "";
        int u = 1;
        while(u<=37) 
        {
            String temp = "";
            int iter = 1;
            for(int i=0; i<seq.length()-1; i++) {
                if(seq.charAt(i)==seq.charAt(i+1)) {
                    iter++;
                    if(i==seq.length()-2) {
                        temp += iter + "" + seq.charAt(i);
                        iter=1;
                    }
                }else {
                    temp += iter + "" + seq.charAt(i);
                    if(i==seq.length()-2) {
                        temp += "1" + seq.charAt(i+1);
                    }
                    iter=1;
                }
            }
            seq=temp;
            output += seq + "\n";
            System.out.println(u + ": " + seq.length());
            u++;
        }
        os.write(output.getBytes(), 0, output.length());
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: [Navigating through Code with the Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: i've tried your code and it printed 37 lines of text.

Comment: how are you viewing the output file? This seems to work correctly, although the string length and byte[] length aren't always the same, they seem to be in this case, so just use os.write(output.getBytes());

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the solution:
I use Eclipse to show the text file but it magically do not show the rest of the file. If I use any other text editor it will show the rest. Maybe the eclipse txt editor can only show a limited amount of text...

Answer (score 0):

If the `String` would be too big to create you would get an `OutOfMemoryException`. This is not the case, your program works and prints 37 lines of numbers with last line being 48410 characters long.

Most likely the editor you are using to view the output fails to render these very long lines. It works in IntelliJ IDEA for me.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I'm using eclipse's internal editor... :)